# How To Override Extension Attributes/configurable_item_options In Orders Rest API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am trying to override the `"configurable_item_options"` of the `product_options` under the orders API.

I want to add a further column between the `option_id` and `option_value`.

[image]

I can see that the "product_options"/"configurable_item_options" of the order Api comes under the **"items"** column. I can also see that the **"items"** column is derived from the  **getItems** method of the following class:

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/Api/Data/OrderInterface.php
```

This is the function:

```
public function getItems()
    {
        if ($this->getData(OrderInterface::ITEMS) == null) {
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(OrderItemInterface::ORDER_ID,$this->getId());

            $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
            $this->setData(
                OrderInterface::ITEMS,
                $this->itemRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems()
            );
        }
        return $this->getData(OrderInterface::ITEMS);
    }
```

**My Question**

how can I override the above section to include a new column?

i tried to override it via a plugin:

```
 <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="delivery_promise_add_custom_config_product_to_sales_order"
                type="Primrose\DeliveryPromise\Plugin\AddCustomAndConfigurableProductAttributes"/>
    </type>
```

The Plugin Class:

```
public function afterGet(
        OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
        OrderInterface $result
    ) {

   $titleName  = ["title_name" => "the New title"];

       $result->setItems($titleName);

        return $result;
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried @LitExtension solution. i.e i tried to reset the Configurable Item Options via the $extensionAttributes but got this message:

```
Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtension::setConfigurableItemOptions(
```

This is my method:

```
public function afterGet(
        OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
         OrderInterface $orderItem
    ){
        
        $extensionAttributes = $orderItem->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();

        $array = ['test' => "new value"];

        $extensionAttributes->setConfigurableItemOptions($array);
        $orderItem->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        return $orderItem;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function afterGet(OrderItemRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderItemInterface $orderItem)
    {
        $customAttrName = $orderItem->getData(self::CUSTOM_ATTR_NAME);
        $extensionAttributes = $orderItem->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
        $extensionAttributes->setCustomAttrName($customAttrName);
        $orderItem->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        return $orderItem;
    }
    public function afterGetList(OrderItemRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderItemSearchResultInterface $searchResult)
    {
        $orderItems = $searchResult->getItems();

        foreach ($orderItems as &$item) {
            $customAttrName = $item->getData(self::CUSTOM_ATTR_NAME);
            $extensionAttributes = $item->getExtensionAttributes();
            $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
            $extensionAttributes->setCustomAttrName($customAttrName);
            $item->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        }
        return $searchResult;
    }
```

Comment: hello . thanks for your kind reply. i am however having problem resetting the configurableItem Options . this is the error message i received: Call to undefined method Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtension::setConfigurableItemOptions()